# How do I change the visibility cycling in orgmode?

Tags: org-mode, visibility

Currently when I press TAB it uses this:

,-> FOLDED -> CHILDREN -> SUBTREE --.

But I would like it to behave like other outliners. If I press TAB once it should open the children. It I press TAB again it should close it. Even if there is a SUBTREE.

Comment: Closely related/possible duplicate: [How to cycle between specified states in org mode?](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/16773/how-to-cycle-between-specified-states-in-org-mode)